# Get tr values from a javascript string which is html code

Tags: javascript, html, fitbit

I need a javascript function (fitbit sdk) for getting all tr with values from a html string.

I tried to split it (tbody) but obj.split("tbody") or  or obj.getElementById don't worked.
Also I can't use innerHTML because it's not supported on the fitbit sdk.

```
var codeFromWebsite = "<html><p>kbjb</p><p>ibk<p><tbody id=""><tr><td></td>....</tr></tbody><p>hjv</p>...</html>"


I want a result like <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>....</tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td>....</tr>...
```

I didn't know how I can make it, but I'm very happy if you could tell me how or if it's possible.

Comment: Manipulating HTML strings with code is tedious and generally not a good idea, but if you clarify your intention we might find another way. Where does the `codeFromWebsite` come from? What will the output be used for? Do you need the output as a string, or do you need DOM elements?

Comment: it's from the online school timetable company dsbmobile. At the end the programm is supposed to show every lesson that is cancelled. (Output as string would be perfect)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `splice()` with `search()`

```
var txt = "<a><B><c><D></D></c></B></a>"
var spliced = txt.splice(txt.search("<B>"), txt.search("</B>" + 4);
return spliced;
```

Would return `<B><c><D></D></c></B>`.

Comment: slice returns nothing

Comment: @KiwiGamingYT Sorry meant `splice`. Edited answer